# How to use RequiredIf annotation in MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

```
[RequiredIf("Typeofproperty", "Typeofproperty != 5 && Typeofproperty != 2", ErrorMessage = "Do you need Two-wheeler parking ?")]        
 public int Twowheelerparking { get; set; }
```

Here Typeofproperty is of type int and control used for it is a radio button. 5 and 2 are the values of radio buttons for Plot and House. I want to validate Twowheelerparking if it is not a plot and house. The code above is not working for this purpose. Please tell me how to do it.

Comment: You need to post the code for the `RequiredIf` attribute (or is this from `Foolproof` or some other library?

Comment: Yes I'm using Foolproof.

Comment: @StephenMuecke - Please tell me what should I do now ?

Comment: Your not using the attribute correctly. Is should be something like `[RequiredIf("Typeofproperty", "2", ErrorMessage = "...")]`. And I don't think you can have multiple conditions. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17795681/how-to-make-a-property-required-based-on-multiple-condition) may point you in the right direction.

Comment: I have tried your way but it is showing the error message in any condition.

Comment: If there is any other way please let me know. Foolproof is not working here properly.

Answer (score 0):

Another simple way for obtaining desired result you can create your own validation attribute and in its isValid method definition you can use validationContext for validating data.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute_methods(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: if looking for example
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687422/customvalidation-attribute-doesnt-seem-to-work

Answer (score 0):

You may checkout the :
[following blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2011/02/04/conditional-validation-in-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx) for a sample implementation of a `[RequiredIf]` custom validation attribute. It compares against a single other property value but you could easily tweak the `IsValid` method to meet your requirements.